# Strikethrough on TextView stays on same row when item is removed from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items on a RecyclerView and when you select an item 'onLongclick' a strikethrough appears over the name of the item. **My problem** is when I delete the item (and call notifyDataSetChanged()) strikethrough remains in the exact same row of the previous item that was deleted but now its a strike over a new item. For example:

**My list** Before the item deleted

1. List item A
2. *List item B* | Item B represent the strikethrough
3. List item C
4. List item D

**My list** After the item deleted

1. List item A
2. *List item C* | Unintended item has strikethrough
3. List item D

When I leave the page and reopen it, then the items are shown correctly with no unwanted strikethroughs appearing which I made sure in my code but I have no idea how to do this when I first delete it the strikethrough. I am new to app development but I feel like I'm just missing an obvious solution maybe or not...thank you in advance.

P.s. My understanding is it's like the strikethrough stays on the exact same recycleViewHolder even when the data changes but I'm not sure what to do in order to undo it without closing and opening the activity.

```js
class ListRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {


    public TextView nameView;
    public TextView categoryView;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public ListRecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        nameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.li_name_view);
        categoryView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.li_category_view);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener){
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.Onclick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.Onclick(v,getAdapterPosition(),true);
        return true;
    }

    public void SetStrike(TextView text,boolean strike){
        if (strike) {
            text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            text.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        } else {
            text.setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
}

public class ListItemAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListRecyclerViewHolder> {

    private List<Inventory> mAllItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public Context context;

    public int selectedItem;

    private List<Inventory> allCrossedItemsOnList = new ArrayList<Inventory>();

    private boolean checkIfEmpty = false;

    public void setItemsAdaptor(List<Inventory> allItems,Context context){
        if(allItems.isEmpty() || allItems == null)
        {
            //No item in the list
            Inventory item = new Inventory();
            item.setName("List Empty!");
            item.setCategory("");
            allItems.add(item);
            this.mAllItems = allItems;
            this.context = context;
            this.allCrossedItemsOnList = null;
            checkIfEmpty = true;
            //when called this updates all items displayed on the list.
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return;
        }
        this.mAllItems = allItems;
        this.context = context;
        this.allCrossedItemsOnList = FindAllCrossedItems();
        checkIfEmpty = false;
        //when called this updates all items displayed on the list.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("TAG","Data Updated Adaptor");


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tab,viewGroup, false);
        return new ListRecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  final ListRecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int i) {


        recyclerViewHolder.nameView.setText(mAllItems.get(i).getName());
        recyclerViewHolder.categoryView.setText(mAllItems.get(i).getCategory());

        //Set the item if they are crossed or not when page is opened.
        if(!checkIfEmpty && allCrossedItemsOnList != null){
            for (Inventory item: allCrossedItemsOnList){
                if(mAllItems.get(i).getId() == item.getId()){
                    recyclerViewHolder.SetStrike(recyclerViewHolder.nameView,true);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (!checkIfEmpty && recyclerViewHolder.nameView.getPaint().isStrikeThruText()) {
            recyclerViewHolder.SetStrike(recyclerViewHolder.nameView,false);
        }

        recyclerViewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void Onclick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClicked) {
                if (!checkIfEmpty) {
                    if (isLongClicked) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected: " + mAllItems.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //selectedItem = position;
                        if (!recyclerViewHolder.nameView.getPaint().isStrikeThruText()) {
                            recyclerViewHolder.SetStrike(recyclerViewHolder.nameView,true);
                            allCrossedItemsOnList.add(mAllItems.get(position));
                            mAllItems.get(position).setCrossedOnList(true);
                            MainActivity.myAppLocalDatabase.myDao().updateItem(mAllItems.get(position));
                        } else {
                            recyclerViewHolder.SetStrike(recyclerViewHolder.nameView,false);
                            allCrossedItemsOnList.remove(mAllItems.get(position));
                            mAllItems.get(position).setCrossedOnList(false);
                            MainActivity.myAppLocalDatabase.myDao().updateItem(mAllItems.get(position));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked: " + mAllItems.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAllItems.size();
    }

    public int getSelectedItem(){return selectedItem;}
    public List<Inventory> getCrossedItems(){return allCrossedItemsOnList;}
    public void setCrossedItems(List<Inventory> crossed) {
        this.allCrossedItemsOnList = crossed;
    }
    //When page opened checks items (my data set) for which items are crossed already.
    private List<Inventory> FindAllCrossedItems(){
        List<Inventory> itemsCrossed = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
        for(Inventory item : mAllItems)
        {
            if (item.isCrossedOnList()) {
                itemsCrossed.add(item);
            }
        }

        return itemsCrossed;
    }
    //Updated database of all the crossed out items on the list that have been deleted.
    public void RemoveAllCrossedItems(){
        for (Inventory item: allCrossedItemsOnList) {
            Log.d("TAG","To be removed "+item.getName());
            item.setCrossedOnList(false);
            item.setAddToList(false);
            MainActivity.myAppLocalDatabase.myDao().updateItem(item);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to clear the list and reload the data after you delete the item from the list.Just an idea @TCKblade

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work and the same behaviour from the list and the strikethrough is happening. It's like the strikethrough stays on the exact same recycleViewHolder even when the data changes but I'm not sure what to do in order to undo it without closing and opening the activity. Thanks anyways @g.brahmaDatta

Comment: can't you set strikethrough in the recyclerview onbindviewholder itself?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have been doing for selecting and deselecting the items in onBindViewHolder by setting 'setItemOnClickListener' but the method I use to delete the items is a button 'Clear all strikethrough' that's separate from the actual recycleview. When pressed it deletes all of the items with a strike but doesn't remove the strike on the RecycleHolder of the previous item that had the strike so when the new set of items (data) is passed to the adaptor an unintended strike appears. Is there possibly a way to access the individual RecycleHolder in the RV outside the onbindviewhold method?

Comment: I used the same concept for the Realm Adapter . It works fine for me.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta Just wanted to let you know that I worked out my problem. I firstly removed notifyDataSetChanged() from setItemsAdaptor function and secondly i changed my RemoveAllCrossedItems() to...                                    
        int i =0;
        for(Inventory item:mAllItems){
            if(item.isCrossedOnList()){
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
                item.setCrossedOnList(false);
                item.setAddToList(false);
                MainActivity.myAppLocalDatabase.myDao().updateItem(item);
            }
            i++;
        }

Comment: Wow, that's awesome @Tckblade.